# Swift Persistant Permission Ask

Tags: ios, swift, ios-permissions

I am creating an app which requires the user to allow the app to capture the screen.
I have implemented the code using ReplayKit2.
The code works great except it asks for the permission:

> Allow screen capture in APP_NAME?
>
> This application will capture your screen and you will not have a chance to review it

I'm fine with the warning coming up once when the user uses the application for the first time, but am receiving an ask for this permission everytime I  restart the app.

Is there any way around the same?

Thanks.